# How to test jsp attribute type

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I have Spring MVC app with user settings. Settings are objects with strings Name, Value, User and Type field.
To edit values form with table is generated and Values are editable strings.

For Settings that have value checkbox in field Type, I would like display checkbox, ie:

```
<c:if test="setting.type=='checkbox'">
   <form:checkbox path="setting.name" />
</c:if>
```

I cannot figure it out. Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens? Any error? Where's the code of Settings? Do you have a getter for the type field?

Comment: You are missin `${}` around the variables.

Comment: Anyone maybe know, how to store checkboc value=(true or false) if attribute is String? For me it toggles from "true" to "".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you try to change

```
<c:if test="setting.type=='checkbox'">
```

to

```
<c:if test="${setting.type=='checkbox'}">
```

?

of course, the 'setting' object must be passed to jsp correctly.

Comment: Thanks! Do you maybe know, how to store checkboc value=(true or false) if attribute is String? For me it toggles from "true" to "".

Answer (score 1):

Did you try ? :

```
<c:if test="${setting.type=='checkbox'}">
   <form:checkbox path="setting.name" /> 
</c:if>
```

Comment: Sorry, @Kent was faster, thanks anyway! Do you maybe know, how to store checkboc value=(true or false) if attribute is String? For me it toggles from "true" to "".